# How can I create a filter control for more than one column in a line graph with Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a table of sales for different days across different Cities, the column list looks like this

```
[Date, Lagos, Accra, Cairo, Johannesburg]
```

So I plot a multiple line graph with a date on X-axis and the Cities as Legend. How can I create a filter to view each city (Column filter) on Google Data Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily is the answer. Ideally you'd transform your data to be in the form

```
DATE | CITY | SALES
```

before importing it and then use city as the filter.